# Is this question off topic on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I accessed an article on the web and really liked the graphics it contained.  I'd like to post a question on SO containing the graphs from the original article asking if anybody knows the tools that were used to generate them (e.g. matlab or Inkscape,...).

Do you think this question would be considered Off Topic on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it’s off-topic, because it doesn’t have anything to do with programming. It’s probably unanswerable, too, unless the generator has put its signature somewhere.

Asking how to make that type of graph with an example of what you’ve tried, however, would probably be fine! =)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that question is off-topic for StackOverflow. Please check the Help Center first; read [this Help Center topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on which topics are acceptable. Your question falls into none of these categories.